# Is there an x86 assembly instruction that does both 'xadd' and 'adc reg,0'?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, instruction-set, carryflag

I've recently learnt about `XADD` and I had no luck at looking up on google. Does an instruction like `XADD` that also adds the carry flag exist? (ex. `XADC`) Or am I forced to do it with two different instructions?

I'm on Ubuntu and I'm using NASM in 64 bits mode.

Comment: No such luck. Use adc reg, 0 before the xadd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.   `xadd` and `adc` are two different niche versions of addition that don't normally overlap, so it's not surprising that x86 doesn't have an instruction for it.

- `xadd` is usually used with a memory destination (and often a `lock` prefix) for atomic_fetch_add
- `adc` is usually used for extended-precision stuff, for the high parts of an integer wider than a register

If you did `lock xadd` / `lock xadc` (hypothetical), you wouldn't be doing a single double-width atomic fetch_add, you'd be doing two separate atomic additions on the two halves of a wider number.  So it's not really useful; if you want to atomic_fetch_add an `__int128`, you need a `lock cmpxchg16b` retry loop, not xadd / "xadc".

If you want to do `fetch_add(&mem, reg) + CF` or `fetch_add(&mem, reg+CF)`, you can do that manually with a combination of `adc` and `xadd` in some order.  (And maybe some branching to handle the case where the `+CF` itself produces a carry if that's a concern).

That's a niche enough need that x86 didn't choose to spend an opcode on it.  There are only a limited number of opcodes, and each one would require transistors in the decoders, and at least microcode to implement it.